# linux executing command in existing screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have found that the following command is good for creating a new screen and running a shell command in it:

```
screen -dmS newscreen -- sh -c 'date; exec $SHELL'
```

However, what if I want to run the exact same shell command, but using an existing screen? I tried the following, but when I entered the screen I saw nothing printed:

```
screen -S existingscreen -X -- sh -c 'date; exec $SHELL'
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me, but without the double hyphens:

```
screen -S existingscreen -X exec sh -c 'date;exec $SHELL'
```